# Merge 2 PDS member to 1

Tags: zos, jcl

I have a seemingly easy task of of merging 2 member of a PDS, say MYDSN.X(A) and MYDSN.X(B) to a common member MYDSN.X(AB).

My attempt was to use **IEBCOPY** but somehow I wasn't able to do this particular task, although I found quite a few helpful examples [here](https://sites.google.com/site/ibmmainframeserver/iebcopy).

A further special case of this task would be to create a new member, say MYDSN.X(A3) that contains 3 times the content of MYDSN.X(A). Any ideas on that special case, too?

Comment: On what basis do you want to "merge" two members? On what basis do you want to triplicate the content of a new member? Of course (likely) these things can be done, if we know the rules.

Comment: Think of MYDSN.X(A) as INPUT for a batch. Now I want to see how the batch performs with large INPUT, say 3, 10 or 100 times the content of MYDSN.X(A).

Comment: Do you want to have member-A followed by member-b in AB; or do you want sort the 2 members together on a key or something else ???

Comment: Sorting is not required. In member AB the content of member A should come first and be followed by the content of member B.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you want to do is very simple with dataset concatenation:

```
//SOMENAME DD DISP=SHR,DSN=yourpds(yourmem1)
//         DD DISP=SHR,DSN=yourpds(yourmem1)
```

You can use that directly in your JCL that runs the step(s) you want to test, or, if you want a permanent copy, you can make a copy:

```
//SORTCOPY EXEC PGM=SORT
//SORTIN   DD DISP=SHR,DSN=yourpds(yourmem1) 
//         DD DISP=SHR,DSN=yourpds(yourmem2)
//SORTOUT  DD DISP=OLD,DSN=yourpds(yournew) 
//SYSOUT   DD SYSOUT=* 
//SYSIN    DD * 
 OPTION COPY
```

Notice the `DISP=OLD` for the output. That will ensure you won't potentially lose data if two jobs doing this run at the same time.

PDSEs are "safer" than PDSs.

If you want multiple copies of the same member:

```
//SORTCOPY EXEC PGM=SORT
//SORTIN   DD DISP=SHR,DSN=yourpds(yourmem1) 
//         DD DISP=SHR,DSN=yourpds(yourmem1)
//         DD DISP=SHR,DSN=yourpds(yourmem1)
//         DD DISP=SHR,DSN=yourpds(yourmem1)
//SORTOUT  DD DISP=OLD,DSN=yourpds(yournew) 
//SYSOUT   DD SYSOUT=* 
//SYSIN    DD * 
 OPTION COPY
```

Using your editor to Repeat is really simple.

Comment: In your first example, do you mean to say:

`//SOMENAME DD DISP=SHR,DSN=yourpds(yourmem1)
//         DD DISP=SHR,DSN=yourpds(yourmem2)`